# Morphing Sphere into Plane

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is there a way to change the `SphereGeometry()` object to flat plane on screen? I want to do it exactly as [this site](http://www.markuslerner.com/travelscope/), so when you click on bottom right buttons, the view is changed. The code below is how the sphere created. Simplicity is important.

```
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    loader.load("js/model/map.jpg", function(texture) {
    var earthMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: texture,
        bumpscale: 0.05
    });
    var earthSphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(80, 32, 32);

    earthSphere = new THREE.Mesh(earthSphereGeometry, earthMaterial);
    scene.add(earthSphere);
})
```

Comment: Hi, did you find out how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Speaking of morphing earth-like sphere into map-like plane - geometry morphing (vertex displacement) works well. Starting with [THREE.SphereBufferGeometry](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/d8b24a1d2d4887a5db77d7112e5ba1539377c905/src/extras/geometries/SphereBufferGeometry.js) wouldn't work good since unwrapped polygonal sphere is [not quite a plane](https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Sphere-Unwrapping.html).

But there are no such problems with [THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/d8b24a1d2d4887a5db77d7112e5ba1539377c905/src/extras/geometries/PlaneBufferGeometry.js). To construct desired object you could use your own [ShaderMaterial](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=shader#Reference/Materials/ShaderMaterial). Such material should compute target sphere-alike morph in vertex shader (either on CPU - then it should be passed as another attribute). Having two states smoothly mix between them using float uniform.

Here is a [working example of such wrapping](https://jsfiddle.net/mlkn/d4r2tndq/) with 77 revision of three.js (use slider to wrap).

```
vec3 anglesToSphereCoord(vec2 a, float r)
{
    return vec3(
        r * sin(a.y) * sin(a.x),
        r * cos(a.y),
        r * sin(a.y) * cos(a.x)  
    );
}

void main() {
    vec2 angles = M_PI * vec2(2. * uv.x, uv.y - 1.);
    vec3 sphPos = anglesToSphereCoord(angles, 0.6);
    vec3 wrapPos = mix(position, sphPos, wrapAmountUniform);

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( wrapPos, 1.0 ); 
}
```

It is worth noticing that this object construction is sensitive to camera position.
In order to hide a cut and have a nice transition at any angle you could fix camera and apply rotation in shader ([rotating not geometry, but uv coordinates](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MlfSz7)). Handling different projections goes there as well.